# Is there any built in support in Ruby/Rails for the formaction button attribute in HTML5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

HTML5 introduced a couple of new attributes where a type=submit button can override the action defined by the form tag, and even specify which form it submits. The button attributes are formaction and form respectively. The first takes a URL and the second an id. Is there any built in support in Ruby/Rails for these new methods of form control?

In my case I would like two buttons on an email form; one to save and send, the other just to save and return.

Comment: There is no standard helper for it yet, but you can easily write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks @dimakura, I'm still relatively new to Ruby so that would probably be a stretch for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard helper for it yet, but you can easily write one yourself.

Comment: Thanks @dimakura. I know how to do it using html in my erb. My question was "Is there any built in support in Ruby/Rails for these new methods of form control?" If you could make your first comment "There is no standard helper for it yet, but you can easily write one yourself." an answer I'd accept it.